# How does Ptolemy's table, of angles in air and angles in water, fit perfectly on a parabola?

Tags: refraction

In "The Feynman Lectures on Physics" Vol.1 Optics Ch.26, Table 26-1 Ptolemy's list of angle in air and angle in water are given, in connection with Snell's law of refraction. I quote below values from that table: The angles are in degrees.

Angle in air,        Angle in water:
   (10,                    8);
   (20,                    15.5);
   (30,                    22.5);
   (40,                    29);
   (50,                    35);
   (60,                    40.5);
   (70,                    45.5);
   (80,                    50).

In table 26-2 the corresponding angles according to Snell's law are given, to show the remarkable agreement with Ptolemy's list.

In the text above the tables, a statement says all these values 'fit pefectly on a parabola'.

I am unable to see the how these values fit on a parabola. How do you get the parabola from the listed values in the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph below shows the given data as red dots, with the angle in air as the x-axis, and the angle in water as the y-axis.  The blue line is a [least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) fit of the data to a line, and the purple line is a least squares fit to a parabola.  The data clearly doesn't quite fit a line, but it does fit very well to a parabola.

The parabola shown, calculated as a least squares fit, is

$$y=0.825 x - 0.0025 x^2\ \ \ .$$

[image]

Comment: The parabola also goes through the (0,0) point, which is nice.